# Keep user logged in but exit android app on double pressing back

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using `Firebase` to sign in the user and have implemented the code to exit the app on double click. But the problem is the same screen is popping up again.

I tried a workaround setting a `SharedPreference` and then checking that in `mAuthListner`. But it did not work.

Here are the relevant sections of the code:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        SharedPreferences d= getSharedPreferences("backPressed", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean t = d.getBoolean("back",false);

        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null && !t) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class));
        }

        if (t) {
            d.edit().putBoolean("back",false);
        }

    }

};
```

Code for back button pressed:

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    }
};

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        SharedPreferences d= getSharedPreferences("backPressed",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        d.edit().putBoolean("back",true);
        finish();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHandler != null) { mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable); }
}
```

How can I exit the app on back pressed twice while keeping the user logged in?

Comment: In my experience, Firebase stays signed in unless you specifically log out.  Closing the app has never signed me out. Are you sure your "am i signed in" logic is correct?  `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null`

Comment: On pressing back twice I am setting the value of t to be true using SharedPreference. I was just trying to disable the redirection if the back is pressed twice

Comment: In that case it isn't clear what you asking. Your latest comment seems to suggest your question is not related to Firebase at all.

Comment: I want to exit the app on back pressing twice keeping the user signed in.

Comment: I find it hard to parse what the back button/shared preference is trying to accomplish here, so will instead comment how Firebase Authentication works when an app exits and restarts. As Kuffs commented: Firebase Authentication does not automatically sign the user out. When you app restarts, the `onAuthStateChanged` will fire and there will be a current user.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a Firebase issue as Firebase will not log out until you specifically call the "Log Out" method.

You do not need SharedPreferences. Just set an Activity level variable `BackOnce` to False then set it in the `OnBackPressed` as necessary.

```
boolean BackOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (BackOnce) {
        finish();
    } else {
        BackOnce = true;

        Snackbar sb = Snackbar.make(myView, "Press back again to close app", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        sb.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);
                BackOnce = false;
            }
        });
        sb.show();
      }
}
```